# Avoid menu to hide when it reaches bottom of parent

Tags: html, css

I have a grid with a number of records. In each record, there is an option to open a small menu. The problem with the menu is that it gets hidden by the browser's edge when it is opened on the last row. For all the row's menu should open downwards that is the requirement. For the last row where the menu is getting cut-off the fix I want is it to open upwards.

```js
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    //debugger;
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden
}

.row {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible
}

.menu {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Menu</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Menu</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Menu</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Menu</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/5mwcvhkr/3/

I am looking for a CSS solution. If not CSS then a minimal JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can target the last `row` and set the menu inside it to open from the bottom...

```js
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    //debugger;
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden
}

.row {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible
}

.menu {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1
}

.row:last-child .menu {
  top: initial;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Menu</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Menu</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Menu</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Menu</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't do that because it is not necessary that the last row touches the edge of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    //debugger;
    var $menu = $(this).next();
    $menu.toggle();
    ensureMenuItemNotHidden($menu);
  });
});

function ensureMenuItemNotHidden($menuItem) {
  // Calculating main bottom position relative to document's top
  var mainMenuBottom = $("#main").offset().top + $("#main").height();
  // Calculating main bottom position relative to document's top
  var menuItemBottom = $menuItem.offset().top + $menuItem.height();
  var menuItemOverflows = mainMenuBottom - menuItemBottom < 0;
  
  // add menu--top class if menu item overflows
  $menuItem.toggleClass("menu--top", menuItemOverflows);
}
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden
}

.row {
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible
}

.menu {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1
}

.menu--top {
  top: initial;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Menu</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Menu</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Menu</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Open Menu</a>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```